# Vaadin incorrect alignment

Tags: java, vaadin

I have the following piece of code that I wrote. I am trying to center both the texts one after another in the panel like this:

```
                            Your name is:
                                  1
```

Can anyone tell me how to go about doing this?

Thank you.

Code:

```
        VerticalLayout layout1 = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSizeFull();
        layout1.setSizeFull();
        Label label = new Label("Your name is: ");
        label.setStyleName(Runo.LABEL_H1);
        Label label1 = new Label(name);
        label1.setStyleName(Runo.LABEL_H1);
        layout1.addComponent(label);

        layout1.addComponent(label1);
        layout1.setComponentAlignment(label, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        layout1.setComponentAlignment(label1, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        layout.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

        setContent(layout);
        panel.setContent(layout1);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels in Vaadin have a default width of 100%, meaning the `Label` component fills the entire horizontal space, leaving no room for alignment. The reason for this default is that in most cases you'll want the text to wrap once it reaches the edge of the parent component.

To center the labels in your code, just set their widths to undefined by doing `label.setWidth(null);`

The reson for the extra vertical space is in the `VerticalLayout`. Since you've set an expicit height for it but haven't specified any expand ratios for the slots, it's making both of the slots equally high; half the height of the layout each. To get around that, you can do one of two things: get rid of the height in `layout1` by replacing the call to `layout1.setSizeFull();` with `layout1.setWidth("100%");`—or set an expand ratio for the second slot by doing `layout1.setExpandRatio(label1, 1);`. Setting the expand ratio will cause the layout to use all the extra space in the second slot, leaving the two labels closer together.

With `setExpandRatio` you'll of course also have to change the alignment of `label1` from `MIDDLE_CENTER` to `TOP_CENTER`, so that the empty space is placed below the label and not evenly around it.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot that helped center the text but I cant get rid of the white space in between them. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I added info on that in the answer.